# Visio 2013 Dynamic connector master options greyed out

Tags: microsoft-visio, editing, connector

I need to use the edit master but its greyed out, how do I stop this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is the **Dynamic connector** in the **Connectors** stencil.

To be able to edit a master shape you need to put the stencil into edit mode (right-click the stencil header area -> Edit Stencil). However, Visio prevents you from editing these built-in stencils.

You need to create a new stencil, copy the shape into this new stencil and edit it there. Then save it into your **My Shapes** folder. You can't replace the original shape.